# Query Multiple fields php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query multiple fields in php and mySQL and cannot get my code to work. The lname variable works fine, but when I search on an email, I get back every record in the table. If I remove the OR and just query on  `"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = '$email' "` then email works and returns just that record. I don't understand why they won't work together. Here is my code:

```
<?php
if ( !empty($_REQUEST['last_name']) || !empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) { 

  // Connect to the database
  require ('../mysqli_connect.php'); 

  $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['last_name']); 
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['email']);   

  $q = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = '$email' or last_name LIKE '%".$lname."%' "; 

  $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

Comment: Assuming the `last name` parameter is empty when you search by `email` only, change `OR` to `AND`. If the `last name` parameter is empty, `OR '%%'` matches absolutely everything in your table.

That said, please familiarise yourself with: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Don't use variables in-line in your query string, even after escaping them.

personal opinion: look at using PDO instead, so much nicer to use. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @Erik. Thanks for the tips! However, `AND` does not work when trying to query on just the `last name.`

Comment: that's fair I had not considered that. You could check if last name has a value and fill it with nonsense if it doesn't. Leave your code as per your example and only change:

$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['last_name']); 

to 

$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, (!isset($_REQUEST['last_name'])?'foobarbaz':$_REQUEST['last_name']));